# change the background image of one div when the mouse is over a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image of one div when the mouse is over a different div, using jQuery.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.linktomouseover').mouseover(function() {
    $(.linktomouseover2).css('background-image', "url('test.jpg')");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linktomouseover">
  <a class="nthn">link1</a>
</div>
<div class="linktomouseover2">
  <a class="test">link2</a>
</div>
```

So when mouse is over div with class `linktomouseover` it will actually change the background of div with class `linktomouseover2`

this does not seem to work. please help?

Comment: your missing quotes for` $(".linktomouseover2")` did you check that?

Comment: Your welcome :-) Kindly accept the answer so that it does not log in unanswered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing  quotes in the code `jQuery(.linktomouseover)`

This is the correct code

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".linktomouseover").mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(".linktomouseover2").css('background-image', "url('test.jpg')");
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/n2hffyp8/)**

Answer (score 1):

this is a mistake on your code.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.linktomouseover2').mouseover(function() {
        $('.linktomouseover').css('background-image', "url('http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/nexusae0_wallpaper_01.jpg')");
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="linktomouseover">
    <a class="nthn">link1</a>
</div>
<div class="linktomouseover2">
    <a class="test">link2</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.linktomouseover{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background:#e7e7e7;
    height:200px;
}
.linktomouseover2{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background:#d7d7d7;
    height:200px;
}
```

---

### [Live Demo On JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9ujy0uz/)

Comment: Thanks for responding, the error you mention was identified by Pbk1303 as well, thanks again